# How to initialize a struct before the do-catch block

Tags: swift

I have a do/catch block which call a function to return a struct
My question is how to initialize myStruct to nil before the do-catch block.

I currently get a compile error 'nil ' cannot initialize specified type MyStruct.

```
func MyFunction() -> MyStruct {
    
    var myStruct : MyStruct = nil
    
    do {
        myStruct = try AFunctionReturnMyStruct()
    } catch NSError
    {
        
    }
    return myStruct
}
```

Comment: Why before? Can't you do the return in the `do`, and so its declaration?

Comment: make your method throw `func myFunction() throws -> MyStruct { try aFunctionReturnMyStruct() }`

Comment: @Larme The guy is assigning nil to a non optional type. Don't expect him to know how to catch errors.

Comment: Uhh.. don't you just need to make your var nullable if you want to allow `nil`?  `var myStruct: MyStruct? = nil`. Xcode even suggests this as a fix.

Comment: btw; for method names in Swift, start with a lowercase letter, and capitalize the first letter of embedded words like: `func myFunction()`, or `aFunctionReturnMyStruct()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it an Optional:

```
func MyFunction() -> MyStruct? {

    var myStruct : MyStruct? = nil

    do {
        myStruct = try AFunctionReturnMyStruct()
    } catch NSError
    {

    } 
    return myStruct
}
```

Note that this will have implications at the call site.

Alternatively, make the function throw:

```
func MyFunction() throws -> MyStruct {
    return try AFunctionReturnMyStruct()
}
```

Again, this will affect the call site.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to store `myStruct` variable, catch error or throw the function, you can simplify your function like below:

```
func MyFunction() -> MyStruct? {
    return try? AFunctionReturnMyStruct()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to initialize your variable as `nil` then you must mark it as Optional.

```
var myStruct : MyStruct? = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the simplest solution is to just `try?`:

```
func myFunction() -> MyStruct? {
    return try? aFunctionReturnMyStruct()         // nowadays we don't even need `return`
}
```

Or, if you're doing this `do`-`catch` because you were doing something with the error, then return the appropriate value accordingly:

```
func myFunction() -> MyStruct? {
    do {
        return try aFunctionReturnMyStruct()
    } catch {
        // do something, e.g. perhaps log the error or whatever
        return nil
    }
}
```

Or you can use your pattern if you want, but you have two choices. You can, of course, initialize the optional struct with `nil`. But you also don’t have to initialize it at all, but just make sure that every path (i.e. both the `do` and the `catch` blocks) set it.

For example, you might consider it immutable unless you really need to do further mutation inside `myFunction`:

```
func myFunction() -> MyStruct? {
    let myStruct: MyStruct?                        // if youreally need to mutate, this can be `var`, but we generally favor immutability if we can

    do {
        myStruct = try aFunctionReturnMyStruct()
    } catch {
        // do something, e.g. perhaps log the error or whatever
        myStruct = nil
    }

    return myStruct
}
```